# How to take user input to find a row number and apply all data in that row to a doc template?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a script that allows a user to automatically take data from a spreadsheet and apply it to a Google Docs template.

My `createTemplate()` function individually takes each row in a sheet and applies it to a doc template.  The function will do this for each row in the active sheet.

I have another function, `chooseRow()`, that allows the user to search for a tagNo. through a prompt.
The tagNo. is a unique identifier for a machine that is stored in the spreadsheet.

Each machine has its own tagNo, and user will always know the tagNo.

This function is logging the row number for me, but I cannot apply the same code as the `createTemplate()` function to actually create the document.

I have tried applying the code from `createTemplate()` to `chooseRow()` to hopefully get the result I am looking for, but it just ended doing the exact same as `createTemplate()`.

I applied the code to the inside of the for loop used in `chooseRow()`.

```
function chooseRow(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
  var result = ui.prompt('Please enter the Tag number of the row you wish to print.', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Process the user's response.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var response = result.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
    ui.alert('Your name is ' + response + '.');
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // User clicked X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('You closed the dialog.');
  }

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();

  for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++){
      if(values[i][j] == response){
        Logger.log(i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
function createTemplate(){
  var sleepInt = 0;
  var templateId = "1uSAcH8F21zEjuprIcE2_d84ojQT24ek85Y1W6L17Xno"; //Template ID (Taken from address bar)
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  ss.toast("starting");
  Utilities.sleep(sleepInt);

  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //starting with row 2 and column 1 as our upper-left most column, get values from cells from 1 row down, and 15 columns along - hence (2,1,1,15)
  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 11, 18).getValues(); 

  ss.toast("created document and adding data");
  Utilities.sleep(sleepInt);

  //Get the title and tag number columns ready.  Also get todays date
  //Keeping this block above the for loop allows the code to run faster as it doesn't have to do a .getRange or recalculate the date every time the loop iterates
  var docTitle = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 11, 1).getValues();//this is grabbing the data in field B2
  var docTitleTagNumber = sheet.getRange(2, 3, 11, 1).getValues();
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

  //apply data to template
  for(var i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var docId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy().getId();
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
    var body = doc.getActiveSection();
    body.replaceText("%SITEID%", row[0]);
    body.replaceText("%TAG%", row[1]);
    body.replaceText("%CATEGORY%", row[2]);
    body.replaceText("%DESCRIPTION%", row[3]);
    body.replaceText("%AREA%", row[4]);
    body.replaceText("%SERIALNO%", row[5]);
    body.replaceText("%MODEL%", row[6]);
    body.replaceText("%MANUAL%", row[7]);
    body.replaceText("%HOOKUP%", row[8]);
    body.replaceText("%WEB%", row[9]); 
    body.replaceText("%CONNECTED%", row[11]);
    body.replaceText("%CALIBRATED%", row[12]);
    body.replaceText("%AUTOMATED%", row[13]);
    body.replaceText("%SAT%", row[14]);
    body.replaceText("%SIGNED%", row[16]);

    doc.saveAndClose();

    ss.toast("added data");
    Utilities.sleep(sleepInt);

    //Copy the modified template into the specific folder, then delete the first copy we made (to modify it)
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
    var newFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("16wRGBVdV0OZ5YfKhqEQSFMsux-ekGCCa");
    newFolder.addFile(file); 

    ss.toast("finished");
    Utilities.sleep(sleepInt);

    //uses i to iterate through each row in the first column
    var newDocTitle = docTitle[i][0];
    var newDocTagNumber = docTitleTagNumber[i][0];

    //apply document names, tag numbers, and dates
    doc.setName(newDocTitle + " " + newDocTagNumber + " " + today);
  }
}
```

The expected output is one document containing all of the data from the row that contains the tagNo. that the user entered into the prompt, but the results I am getting are the same as `createTemplate()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I was taking the entire for loop in `createTemplate()` and applying it inside the if statement in `chooseRow()`.  This can be solved by taking the following code in `createtemplate()`,

```
    var row = data[i];
    var docId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy().getId();
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
    var body = doc.getActiveSection();
    body.replaceText("%SITEID%", row[0]);
    body.replaceText("%TAG%", row[1]);
    body.replaceText("%CATEGORY%", row[2]);
    body.replaceText("%DESCRIPTION%", row[3]);
    ...

    body.replaceText("%AUTOMATED%", row[13]);
    body.replaceText("%SAT%", row[14]);
    body.replaceText("%SIGNED%", row[16]);

    doc.saveAndClose();

    ss.toast("added data");
    Utilities.sleep(sleepInt);

    //Copy the modified template into the specific folder, then delete the first copy we made (to modify it)
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
    var newFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("16wRGBVdV0OZ5YfKhqEQSFMsux-ekGCCa");
    newFolder.addFile(file); 

    ss.toast("finished");
    Utilities.sleep(sleepInt);

    //uses i to iterate through each row in the first column
    var newDocTitle = docTitle[i][0];
    var newDocTagNumber = docTitleTagNumber[i][0];

    //apply document names, tag numbers, and dates
    doc.setName(newDocTitle + " " + newDocTagNumber + " " + today);
```

along with the appropriate variables, and pasting it into the if statement here, beneath `Logger.log(i);`

```
for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++){
      if(values[i][j] == response){
        Logger.log(i);
      }
    }
  }
```